# Split string in Array by space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get my array reversed without using the reverse() method. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the code that I have for now. I think I'm close but I'm stuck.

```js
var zin = ["Kan jij achterstevoren praten?"];
var woorden = zin.split(" ");
woordenOmgedraaid = achterstevoren(woorden);

document.write(woordenOmgedraaid);


function achterstevoren(omgedraaid) {
  var length = omgedraaid.length;
  var woordenOmgedraaid = [];
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = omgedraaid.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    woordenOmgedraaid[counter] = omgedraaid[i];
    counter += 1;
  }

  return woordenOmgedraaid;
}
```

Comment: the console errors tell you that `zin.split` is not a function. the reason is simple: arrays don't have a split function. you either have to change it to a string or use: `zin[0].split` to get access to the string that is inside your array.

Comment: Okay, I did that, but it's only giving me a komma when I run it.

Comment: you should seriously consider switching your development environment then because it clearly tells me this: `Uncaught TypeError: zin.split is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Take the brackets off the "zin" variable.

```js
var zin = "Kan jij achterstevoren praten?";
var woorden = zin.split(" ");
woordenOmgedraaid = achterstevoren(woorden);

console.log(woordenOmgedraaid);



function achterstevoren(omgedraaid) {
    var length = omgedraaid.length;
    var woordenOmgedraaid = [];
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = omgedraaid.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        woordenOmgedraaid[counter] = omgedraaid[i];
        counter += 1;
    }

    return woordenOmgedraaid;
}
```

Comment: Those brackets are rather important considering he's asking how to  reverse an array

Comment: Exactly, it has to be an array

Comment: .split('  ') turns the string into an array. Working with the code here, this is the solution I thought she was looking for instead of reversing an array with only one value in it. Otherwise the zin variable should be written ["Kan", "jij", "achterstevoren", "praten?"]. You could also use zin[0].split(' ') using the original array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a for loop that goes backwards through an array, you can simply write it as:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

var reversedArr = []

for (var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedArr.push(arr[i])
}

console.log(reversedArr)
```